# Uninstalled ubuntu and want to install it again

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

As a new Linux user, I encountered a problem during the customization of my dual-boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu system. After restoring a snapshot using Timeshift, my Ubuntu installation became unstable. In an attempt to resolve the issue, I mistakenly formatted the Ubuntu partition, leaving only Windows. Now, I'm unable to boot into Windows without manually specifying the bootloader location. I've explored bcdedit to automate the process but haven't found a solution. Can I reinstall Ubuntu in the existing partition to restore normal boot functionality? Or is there a way to repair bcdedit to resolve the booting issue?
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/17zus4i/newbies_story_of_ubuntu_and_plz_help/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Try running Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  


Boot Ubuntu from a USB drive and follow the "2nd option" instructions in the link above. This has solved the not being able to boot into Windows issue you describe for me many times in the past.